# node + react + heroku, node route 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, create-react-app

FE in react set up with create-react-app
BE in node

I deployed the app on heroku and all looks good but when I do a get to my BE I get a 404 (Not Found).

```html
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');


app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
require('./server/routes')(app);
app.listen(port);
console.log('server started '+ port);
```

this is the route

```html
module.exports = function (app) {
  let apiUrlBase = "/api/v1";

  app.get(`${apiUrlBase}/get-report/:_email`, (req, res) =>  {
    const email = req.params._email;
    axios.get(`https://www.beenverified.com/hk/dd/email?email=${email}`)
    .then(response => {
      let parserNames = utils.getNames(response.data);
      let parserEmails = utils.getEmails(response.data);
      let parserJobs = utils.getJobs(response.data);
      let parserSocials = utils.getSocials(response.data);
      let report = { "names": parserNames, "emails": parserEmails, "jobs": parserJobs, "socials": parserSocials };
      res.json(report);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your express app distinguishes both your api endpoint and your react app endpoint if you are serving both the api and the react app in one express instance. I ran into a similar problem. See [Redux-Saga with babel/webpack "actions must be plain objects..." error in production but not dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741448/redux-saga-with-babel-webpack-actions-must-be-plain-objects-error-in-produc)